# Adding legend to a plotted histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

How can I a menage to add a label to a histogram, after its plotting?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]

n, bins_edges, patches = ax1.hist(x, log=True, bins='doane', color="red")
binwidth =  bins_edges[1] - bins_edges[0]
mylabel = "Binwidth {}".format(binwidth)
ax1.hist[-1].set_label(mylabel)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by label? Where do you want that label to appear? Why do you want to add it *after* creating the histogram?

Comment: I want to show a label inside the plot's legend and I need to show a value that is calculated after I plot the histogram (the value depends on the histogram binning, like I show in the example)

Answer (score 0):

You can add string to legend by passing it to `legend()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x = [2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4]

n, bins_edges, patches = ax1.hist(x, log=True, bins='doane', color="red")
binwidth =  bins_edges[1] - bins_edges[0]
mylabel = "Binwidth {}".format(binwidth)


ax1.legend([mylabel])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Simple like that :O, thanks. If I want to add two "mylabels" how can I achieve that?

Comment: Must be simple as well. Can you try and post your difficulty that you face with that? Think of SO as your last resort: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users